# Drupal 8 how to add Bootstrap class to View Block

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-8

I just started on using Drupal, and i have downloaded the newest version 8 and downloaded bootstrap theme which is still in alpha (and made child theme). Since there arent that many tutorials for 8 i tried to learn it from tutorials of 7. But now i dont know how to add class to a View. In advanced (if i go edit the view) it has CSS class and if i add `col-md-6` it will give that class to block but not the view itself (which is section with a generated class).

So my question is how can i add class to View so i can have. Two views blocks be `col-md-6` or `col-md-9` + `col-md-3`

**EDIT:**

Example:

[image: example of what i need]

What i want is that Articles and Promoted project Block view to be `col-md-6`, so they can be in the same row (next to each other). Also to add from  google-ing i found that i may have to overwrite `block.vars.php` and add class trough there. I might be wrong but will try it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it like this

in the root of my theme i overwrote **block.vars.php** and added

```
switch ($variables['attributes']['id'])
 {
 case 'block-views-block-promoted-project-block-1':
     $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'col-md-6';

     break;
 case 'block-views-block-test-view-block-1':
     $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'col-md-6';

     break;
 }
```

It might not be best solution but it works. If anyone knows how to do this better feel free to comment/answer

Answer (score 1):

1. In your view format select grid format.
2. Add your row class in custom row class and columns class in custom column class box. If like default class then uncheck default column class and default row class.

[image: see this image]

Comment: I tried it this way but its still the same as i would have put it in Advanced. Only this will give class to every row (or column) of fields, but not to whole Block View. But from google-ing i found that i may have to overwrite `block.vars.php` and add class trough there.

Comment: if you need to add a class for view goto advanced settings of view under  other section add class in css class option

Comment: I did try it that way but it only gives the class to the block not the view. But thanks for the help anyway i forgot that you can add class to the grid or list itself.